# Why is this successful brute force with John the Ripper unsuccessful as pw

Tags: brute-force

Trying to resurrect a very old ppt file (2003 Office) So, get the hash

```
python3 ./office2john.py ./<filename>.ppt >hash.txt
```

After compiling the software under ubuntu (the build passed all its tests)

```
./src/john/run/john ./hash.txt
```

jtr eventually brute forces a key with the message on the next line reading …

```
   ./src/john/run/john --show --format=oldoffice ./hash.txt  
<file name>.ppt:<password>

1 password hash cracked, 0 left


Got rid of salt no remaining hashes
```

”
The password does not work though.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

It occurred to me that I may need to open it using office 2003 which I no longer have. I am cracking on Linux (ubuntu) but my "office" lives on MacOS Monterey

Also

```
./src/john/run/john --show --format=oldoffice ./hash.txt  
<filename>.ppt:<password>

1 password hash cracked, 0 left
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/password-protection-for-presentations-in-powerpoint-33dfadad-f231-4bd1-8bf6-d15e1671da41

Comment: Hmm you gotta account that john the ripper is also kinda wonky, but it shouldn't fail here..

Comment: Thankyou @caffeineAddiction ! up to now I have repeatedly been told "Not Here" with no suggestion of where.

Comment: please do not repost

Comment: @schroeder I have addressed the repost issue elsewhere. Frankly, I wish that the question had attracted as much attention  people who knew about the topic in question rather than people whose life purpose appears to be to find questions to criticise, neg or delete.

Comment: BTW, someone (I assume @CaffeineAddiction) moved the question for me. Definitely in the category of a 'kind or useful' action. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I moved it here. And no one was "critiquing", "negging", or "deleting". Your question was unanswerable because it had no detail. I asked for detail, which you provided, which was great. But then you reposted the question word for word, which meant there was a duplicate. The duplicate needed to be resolved, and since this was to be migrated, I deleted the duplicate. No one is "out to get you". We're trying to answer you...

Comment: Well, in that case, thank you for the move and then CaffeineAddict for their insight. 
I have been around Stack Overflow in its various forms since directly addressing a stack was a rational thing to do. Also I have a high degree of tolerance for the antics of people on forums. However, you have not got the complete picture. 
The thing that really got me was about half a dozen people separately duping a post. They must have been able to see that others had already done so and then, ultimately 6 of them heaping a neg on.  Helpful or kind  or say nothing.